# Make mouse cursor travel to a position?

Tags: vb.net, automation, mouse-cursor, cursor-position

I know how to make the cursor move to a position using the following:

```
Cursor.Position = New Point(XPosition, YPosition)
```

But doing just that causes it to move there instantly, I would like for it to travel from the current position to the new position at a set speed.

The speed would be determined by two factors:

1 - The distance between the current and new position - EG. Going from 0X to 500X at a speed of 5px/s compared to going from 0X to 1000X at a speed of 10px/s).

2 - A limited timeframe to get to the target position.

I only know of a messy way of doing this which would be something similar to:

```
If Cursor.Position.X < XPosition Then 
    Dim Speed as Integer = XPosition - Cursor.Position.X
    While Cursor.Position.X < XPosition
        Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + Speed, Blah..)
    End While
End If
'Etc..
```

This would require several If statements checking whether the current X/Y positions are over/under the target X/Y positions.

Is there any way I could make the code for doing this much cleaner?

Comment: Take a look at this library:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need the parametric equation for a line:

`x = x1 + (x2-x1)*t`

where
`x1` = start x,
`x2` = end x, and
`t` = time between 0 and 1.

so if you wanted the cursor to move from `x1(10,20)` to `x2(30,60)` over 10 seconds...

1 second in:
      `x = 10 + (30-10)*.1  ; x = 12`
      `y = 20 + (60-20)*.1  ; y = 24`
2 seconds in:
      `x = 10 + (30-10)*.2  ; x = 14`
      `y = 20 + (60-20)*.2  ; y = 28`
3 seconds in:
      `x = 10 + (30-10)*.3  ; x = 16`
      `y = 20 + (60-20)*.3  ; y = 32`
etc.

**Edit:**
Ideone of this in action (don't use VB often, so its not perfect)
http://ideone.com/c9iLTA